# How to hide a particlar column in DefaultTableModel from displaying it in table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, defaulttablemodel

I am using Java Swingx framework. I have 4 columns in my `DefaultTableModel` object. I wish to display only 3 of the columns. But, I need all four for computing.

### Actual data model

`S.No. | ID | GDC ID | Decsription`

### What I want to display in table

`S.No.| GDC ID | Decsription`

Is it possible to hide or omit only one column from rendering? Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a columns in JTable Invisible for Swing Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492217/how-to-make-a-columns-in-jtable-invisible-for-swing-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- by default minimum size is `10 pixels` widht,
- [you can to remove / add column from JTable view, column presents in the XxxTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/714968), you can to hide and show any of column(s)

Answer (score 4):

No need to adjust your model, or to try to make that column very small. `JTable` has built-in functionality for this: the [`removeColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) method. As stated in the javadoc of that method

> Removes aColumn from this JTable's array of columns. Note: this method does not remove the column of data from the model; it just removes the TableColumn that was responsible for displaying it.

Also note the existence of the following methods:

- [`JTable#convertColumnIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29)
- [`JTable#convertColumnIndexToView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29)

Since the column order and column count in the view (the `JTable`) might be different from the one in the model you need those methods to switch between view and model

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it by setting its width to 0.

```
_table.getColumn("ID").setPreferredWidth(0);
_table.getColumn("ID").setMinWidth(0);
_table.getColumn("ID").setWidth(0);
_table.getColumn("ID").setMaxWidth(0);
```

Comment: There is built-in functionality to 'hide' a column from the view, which is better then meddling with the size

Answer (score 1):

try this to remove a single column:

```
myTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
myTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"S.No.", "ID", "GDC ID", "Decsription"});
JTable myTable = new JTable(myTableModel);

// remember to save the references
TableColumn myTableColumn0 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
TableColumn myTableColumn1 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
TableColumn myTableColumn2 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
TableColumn myTableColumn3 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);

myTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(myTableColumn1);
```

Then to show the column again keeping the order:

```
// 1- remove all the existent columns
myTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(myTableColumn0);
myTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(myTableColumn2);
myTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(myTableColumn3);

// 2- add all the columns again in the right order
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(myTableColumn0);
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(myTableColumn1);
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(myTableColumn2);
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(myTableColumn3);
```

Sorry, but that's the best way I know.

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate the getValueAt , getColumnCount to achieve this.

So for example the getColumnCount you give it as 3

and on getValueAt - to skip if the column index is above the skipped column

JTable will first call getColumnCount and getRowCount and fetch calling getValueAt for each of the cells.

NOTE: Ignore this and see link by trashgod below.

Comment: Right, the `JTable` view displays only what the `TableModel` provides; see also this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/230513).

Comment: You shouldn't touch/alter the `TableModel` for this as the `JTable` has this functionality built-in. See my answer or @trashgod link. If you go for the model-modification, I suggest to use a decorator

Comment: @Robin - agree - i think thats a better solution.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, I overlooked the use of `DefaultTableModel`. Your and mKorbel's answer will likely prove easier in that context. I commonly use Sid's approach in a subclass of `AbstractTableModel`. Depending on usage, brainless may yet want to consider this option.