# How can I delete the column and its underlying data without hiding it in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having difficulties with deleting the actual data under a particular column which I am trying to delete.
I  actually want to delete the column and its underlying data. I am able to insert new columns but when I delete
and insert again, the old columns which I previously deleted pop up again.

Any sort help is appreciated.

Thank you in advancce.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a particlar column in DefaultTableModel from displaying it in table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195973/how-to-hide-a-particlar-column-in-defaulttablemodel-from-displaying-it-in-table)

Answer (score 2):

The data is stored in the `TableModel`.

Deleting the column from the `ColumnModel` will only prevent the view (the `JTable`) from showing it.

In order to remove it, you need to tell the `TableModel` to remove the column data as well.

Depending on you implementation, you could use `JTable.setValueAt(value, row, column)` or `TableModel.setValueAt(value, row, column)`, which ever is more convenient.

This of course assumes you've implemented the `setValueAt` method

Comment: right there no reason to delete Column, use setValueAt() instead

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, I managed to delete the underlying data by using the following as I did not implement the setValueAt method. Sorry for not responding early soon as I got the answer confirming that I managed to find it.

Comment: I will try out your answers as well to make my programme  short.

Answer (score 0):

public void removeColumnAndData(JTable table, int vColIndex) {
         MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();

```
     TableColumn col =table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
     int columnModelIndex = col.getModelIndex();
     Vector data = model.getDataVector();
     Vector colIds = model.getColumnIdentifiers();

  // Remove the column from the table
     table.removeColumn(col);

  // Remove the column header from the table model
     colIds.removeElementAt(columnModelIndex);

  // Remove the column data
     for (int r=0; r<data.size(); r++) {
        Vector row = (Vector)data.get(r);
        row.removeElementAt(columnModelIndex);
     }
     model.setDataVector(data, colIds);

  // Correct the model indices in the TableColumn objects
  // by decrementing those indices that follow the deleted column
     Enumeration<TableColumn> enum1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
     for (; enum1.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        TableColumn c = (TableColumn)enum1.nextElement();
        if (c.getModelIndex() >= columnModelIndex) {
           c.setModelIndex(c.getModelIndex()-1);
        }
     }
     model.fireTableStructureChanged();
  }
```

/********MyDefaultTableModel class*******/

```
   class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
  {
     String columns[];
     int size;

      public MyTableModel(String col[],int size)
     {
        super(col,size);
        columns = col;
        this.size=size;
     }

      public Vector getColumnIdentifiers()
     {
        return columnIdentifiers;
     }
  }
```